# toObject() on the result of aggregate method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Since aggregate method returns result object and not mongoose model, I am not sure how to apply toObject() to transform the fields in the result.

However, find() returns a mongoose model and toObject() transforms the fields as per my requirement.

Any pointers to either change the aggregate() method to return a mongoose model or calling toObject() on the result of aggregate() would be helpful.

below code returns a Mongoose model on which I can call toObject()

```
return model.find(
{
    loc: {
        $nearSphere: {
            $geometry: this.loc,
            $maxDistance: radiusInKm * 1000 
        }
    }
},
cb
);
```

below code is to aggregate which returns a result object

```
return model.aggregate()
.near({

    near: this.loc,// this.loc already has a variable of type point.
    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
    maxDistance: radiusInKm * 1000,
    includeLocs: "dist.location",
    spherical: true

}).exec(cb);
```

I would like to call toObject() as I need to transform the result as below

```
mySchema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret) {

    ret.latitude = ret.loc.coordinates[1];
    ret.longitude = ret.loc.coordinates[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.storeImages.length; i++) {
        ret.storeImages[i] = config.get("cdn.mediaURL") + doc.storeImages[i];
    }
    delete ret.loc;
    delete ret.__v;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to call `.toObject()`? It's already a "plain" JavaScript object ( or more accurately an "array of plain objects" ) which is all the method on mongoose documents is doing. So it's just not required. Nothing stopping you from directly manipulating the results. Nothing to do here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have added my toObject() transformation. I need to call this in order to change manipulate the result. I may have taken a completely wrong approach to do this. Please correct me.

Comment: Feel free to be corrected. It's already a plain JavaScript object. Just manipulate the result. There is nothing stopping you. I have already stated that. How about writing as an independent function and then simply assign it to the `.toObject()` but on your aggregate result just call the function directly. The results are not connected to the schema, so you can't use a method attached to the schema. Separate it.

Comment: I never thought about this :) it worked. thanks a lot for your help..